# WooCommerce - Stop assigning order numbers

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

Let's say that the last order in a woocommerce store have an order number of #100. I want to have an option(button or whatever) to stop assigning order numbers to the future orders, until I click that button again and define a new starting number for those undefined orders.

This is how it should look:

```
#99 - Order($50)
#100 - Order($40)
-----button clicked-----
#(no number) - Order ($100)
#(no number) - Order ($200)
```

Now when I click a button again(which will make woocommerce back to normal again), I will only need to define a new starting order number.

Let's say that I have defined a new starting number to be 321. This is how orders should look now:

```
#99 - Order($50)
#100 - Order($40)
#321 - Order ($100)
#322 - Order ($200)
```

I have no better way of explaining this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this something you'd want to more than once, or is it just a temporary measure? For my curiousity, what's the business reason why you want to do this?

Comment: I assume orders are stored in wp_post, and it looks like it uses the post ID by default. There is a filter woocommerce_order_number, which you could override to return an empty string or null when you want to stop generating order numbers, but then you'd have to find where the order numbers are stored (wp_postmeta?) to go back and fill them in afterwards.

Comment: @Rup My client has online and offline orders and she wants to connect order numbers from both online and offline customers. I will use an example from the question: Last order number before the button is clicked is #100. She will then write invoices for offline customers(on paper) and on the first invoice, the order number will be #101, then #102, etc. When she finishes writing those invoices(last offline invoice number is #320), she will define that the new starting number for orders is #321 and woocommerce will just continue working as usual until next button click